# Why Java 8 allocates 1.07 gb MetaSpace, but uses only 81mb?

Tags: garbage-collection, java-8

I am analyzing GC log from my application.
I wonder why my JVM allocated 1.07 gigabyte for Meta Space, but used only 81 megabytes.

I use jdk8_8.91.14 (Oracle JDK) without any additional settings for memory.

Those numbers come from analyzing GC log file (-XX:+PrintGCDetails ) with http://gceasy.io/

All used metatada was allocated shorty after application was started, and it stays that way for whole applicaton lifetime.

[image]

Why JVM defaults are so wastefull when in comes to metadata? 
It seems, that in my case I just waste 1GB of memory.

How to safely tune Metadata, so it starts small (like 52Mb), grows only when needed, and grows in small chunks?

I am running application on (Virtual Machine), `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`.
Inside that VM , I have docker with `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`

Comment: Does this cause any *actual problem* besides showing that number in a diagram?

Comment: Not much problem for now . Apart from number on the diagram, it is actual memory allocated and used (on OS level). But, because it is not used on Java level, it is a waste, 1GB less for something more useful (heap, native memory ,other processes)

Comment: You didn’t name the OS. On my system, running a no-op Java program on a 64Bit JVM, *reserves* 1GB meta space, but has only 4MB *committed* and 2MB *used* (the term “allocated” does not exists in the GC log). The standard OS level tools show only committed space, though, of course, the OS will have knowledge about reserved sizes. But well, in a 64Bit address space, neither “reserved” nor even “committed but unused” RAM has any meaning. That are only numbers in a maintenance table…

Comment: added OS details into question. I think you are right- Metadata is committed/reserved not actually used. How to make sure that it is the case (which commands to use?)